# AttributeError: module 'torch._C' has no attribute 'HalfStorageBase'

Tags: encryption, pytorch

I use the crypten module(pip install crypten) to do some works, but when I use 'import crypten', the IDE told me this question:AttributeError: module 'torch._C' has no attribute 'HalfStorageBase', and I don't know how to sovle this problem

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with the `crypten` module, and I resolved it by downgrading from `torch==1.11.0` to `torch==1.9.0` using

```
pip install torch==1.9.0
```